# ltrim with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to capture an encoded URL.

I looks something like: #?var=asdasdasdasdasd

I need to strip "#?" at the beginning of the string. In PHP I'd use ltrim. How can I do this with jQuery or plain JS?

```
 $("#myLink").click(function(){
       var myUrl = $(this).attr("href");
       var cleanUrl = ....

 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use replace method.

```
var cleanUrl = myUrl.replace(/^#\?/, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `substr(2)`. It's more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ways to solve your problem.

```
$("#myLink").click(function(){
   var myUrl = $(this).attr("href");
   var cleanUrl = ...??? // what goes here.
}
```

Method 1: Use String.prototype.replace.

```
var cleanUrl = myUrl.replace( /^#\?/, "" );
```

Method 2: Use String.prototype.split

```
var cleanUrl = myUrl.split( "#?" ).pop();
```

Method 3: Use String.prototype.match

```
var cleanUrl = (myUrl.match( /^#\?(.)*/ )||[myUrl]).pop();
```

Extra Method:

```
var i = myUrl.indexOf( "#?" );
i = ( i < 0) ? 0 : i + 2;
var cleanUrl = myUrl.substring( i );
```

Answer (score 0):

var trim = values.trim();

this will remove all the whitespaces.

Comment: But the question is not about removing white spaces.